# UICollectionView horizontal scroll layout issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a somewhat odd problem with my UICollectionView:

The collection view is placed in a UITableViewCell and is supposed to show a horizontally scrollable list of items.

So far almost everything is working, the only problem that I am faced with is that the last item is only visible if you scroll and hold (!) - if you let go of the screen it scrolls back to previous item.
Furthermore it positions the last item at a different y coordinate then the rest of them which looks like this:

[image]

And to introduce even more complexity I have found that for some reason both of the above described behaviours don't always appear but instead seem to depend on some factor I have not yet been able to identify.

The way I'm configuring my layout object looks like this:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(87, 26);
flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10;
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

This is done in my UITableViewCell subclass while my table view controller acts as the data source for the collection view.

Can anyone tell me what caused this behaviour and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so have found that the issue is in some way connected to using self-sizing cells. I am now calculating the size for each cell manually an my layout problems are gone...